# Create table stats from Json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a Json result like so

```
{"goals":["1","1"],"minutes":["12","34"],"player":["1","1"]}
```

And i am trying to create a table with rows displaying each stat like so

```
Goals Minutes Player

1     12        1

1     34        1
```

I currently have this code written up and although i am getting teh data its not quite working the way i want it to. Im not so clued up on Json and the displaying of it as you can see.

```
<?php

$jsonresult =  $this->item->results;

$phpArray = json_decode($jsonresult, true);

foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {

foreach ($value as $k => $v) {

?>

 <tr><td><?php echo $v; ?></td></tr>


<?php }} ?>
```

Cheers
Jonny

Comment: Do you control what the JSON looks like?

Comment: Hi Sverri, Unfortunatley no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$json = '{"goals":["1","1"],"minutes":["12","34"],"player":["1","1"]}';
$array = json_decode($json,true);

print_r($array);    

print "Goals, Minutes, Player\n";

foreach($array['goals'] as $key => $value) {
  print $value . ',' 
  . $array['minutes'][$key] . ','
  . $array['player'][$key] . "\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
Goals, Minutes, Player
1,12,1
1,34,1
```

Comment: Thanks fo rthis. I do undertsand your answer so thats really good but $array['goals'] ? could that be Minutes or Players - just trying to undertsnad why goals is in there as oppposed to the others.

Comment: Yes, it could be minutes or players. The assumption is that `goals` `minutes` and `players` all contain the same keys

Comment: Aha OK very cool. In this case all fields are required and will always have the same number of entries. Thank you so much for explaining that bit. Im learning :)

Comment: Aha again, and i see that the first print is actually the goals values and then preceding is minutes and player. Thanks heaps for this. Tested and working for what i need.